# Creating my own POS tablet

Tags: tablet

Ive been looking into POS (point of service) systems for restaurants/retail, and wish to create a system like this myself, making my own software. 
However, i am having trouble finding any manufacture with a tablet that you can put your own software onto. Just wondering if anyone has had experience with this type of thing and could point me in the right direction.

Something like this is what i have in mind, However i do not need a card reader or anything, just simply something small, with wifi, and touchscreen.

https://www.clover.com/shop/product/mini-table-service/lte

some info - 
must be a tablet
budget is around 200 per tablet. 
must be able to put custom firmware on the device
would like it to be unbranded/be able to put my own brand on it

Answer (score 1):

I have work experience with a few retail companies, and have provided technical support for various POS systems as well. Every single system I have seen or worked with is running a standard operating system under the hood.

- Windows
- Android
- iOS
- Linux

All of these POS systems hid the operating system from end-users by removing OEM logos, replacing or hiding OS menus/graphics, making their app fullscreen, etc.

Taking the Clover POS tablet you linked as an example; This product [is actually running a custom Android OS](https://docs.clover.com/clover-platform/docs/clover-architecture) and the Clover software is essentially just an Android app!

I suggest that you look for a touchscreen device running one of the common operating systems and begin developing an app for that device. Regardless of which OS you work with, it can later be customized to be transparent to end-users.

If you really want to go as far as creating your own OS for a tablet, you can make a custom version of Android using the [Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/). The device you are developing for must be unlocked and it will likely require additional code or patches from the device manufacturer.